# HFSS SAR anlysis Calculation

Tags: antenna, design, simulation, electromagnetism

I am calculating The SAR anlysis on a human head of a wearable antenna that i have made . I have added a waveguide port and after simulation it does not show the radiation pattern 
using the HFSS software 19 version [this is the file that i have been working on](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15wuI37c17bQlqiXaPpASb6ctd01QID4R/view?usp=sharing) 
and  [this the paper i am following](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mD6tHg8unfcsvqgmAfJKCxSAhGbmrtLV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You forgot to state clearly your question: how can we help you?

Comment: I have attached the project , the results are not showing for the SAR after the analyse all I select the human head and choose the plot AVERAGESAR

Comment: I can’t read your project file, but this site shows how to do it. https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_i_find_out_the_SAR_specific_absorption_rate_in_HFSS_Which_command_will_I_have_to_use

Comment: i have tried the above method 
also the file can only be opened using ansys HFSS